# Error installing NPM for node.js

Tags: linux, bash, node.js, ubuntu-11.04, npm

I'm trying to install `npm` on ubuntu 11.04 using the "git all the way" method found in  [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1232821)

I keep getting this error after running `sudo make install` on `npm`

```
$ sudo make install
! [ -d .git ] || git submodule update --init --recursive
node cli.js install -g -f
bash: node: command not found
make: *** [install] Error 127
```

I know this is something wrong with `bash`, but I'm not very good with bash.

**EDIT**

running the `node` command in the terminal brings up the `node` `shell` as expected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that when you sudo, you are not sourcing the same bashrc file (or whatever is setting your PATH and/or NODE_PATH), and so the system cannot find node.

I would guess that `sudo node` won't work.

You need to export your NODE_PATH as @Ken suggested, WHILE SUDOING:

```
sudo PATH=/path/to/node/bin/dir:$PATH make install
```

EDIT: to use PATH as worked in comments below

Comment: You are correct `sudo node` doesn't work. I just tried running `sudo NODE_PATH=~/local/bin make install` as you suggested and got the same error

Comment: Try just with PATH=~/local/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you export NODE_PATH before installing npm.

```
export NODE_PATH=/path/to/node/install/dir:/path/to/node/install/dir/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: I will try that, but just as a question how is that different from `echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc` outlined in the gist. It may sound silly but like I said I'm not good at bash so would be keen to understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have node installed. You need node first - then the node package manager (NPM).

Comment: No idea why this was downloaded.  Upvoting because node was indeed not installed due to path issues as identified by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This [page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) illustrates the complete node installation including npm (step 4).

Comment: I did follow the steps outlined in alternative installation methods on step 3. Which points to a gist by isaacs the author of npm and who is on the node core team

Comment: @ashmokhberi: How have you installed node and what version is it?

Comment: I installed node following the "git all the way" method found in this gist https://gist.github.com/1232821. `Node` is `v4.12` and `npm` is `v 1.30`

Answer (score 0):

Like someone mentioned - why just use yum

```
sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
```